# Python Equivalent to JMX and Jconsole?

Tags: python, jmx, jconsole

Well, this question is pretty simple.

Does Python (including third party solutions) have anything similar to JMX and Jconsole?

Answer (score 2):

Try [PyMX](https://code.google.com/p/pymx/):

> The Python Management Extensions (PyMX) is a Python analog to Java's
>   JMX. PyMX aims to be an API for the management and monitoring of
>   resources such as applications, devices, services, as well as the
>   Python interpreter.